# echo product parent category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

im trying to echo the product sub category name with link.
but im getting the full categories ( parent + sub categories )

```
function add_category_above_product_title() {
    global $product;
    $product_category_ids = wc_get_product_term_ids( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
    if ( ! empty( $product_category_ids ) ) {
        echo 'Category: ';
        foreach( $product_category_ids as $cat_id ) {
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $cat_id, 'product_cat' );
            $link = get_term_link( $term, 'product_cat' );
            echo '<a href="'.esc_url($link).'">'.$term->name.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_category_above_product_title', 2 );
```

Comment: What sub category you want to display? any sub category or only sub categories of the current category? in `woocommerce_single_product_summary` you don't really have a main category, unless you use a plugin. `wc_get_product_term_ids` gets all categories that the product is connected to

Comment: i want to display the current category..
for example :
 I have product in :

- Cloths
-- T-shirts
--- H&M

I want to display the H&M category name ( with clickable link )